# Having Issue on Getting Second Session Variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a PHP file getting data from my SQL database and I am trying to set and get two session variables like `$_SESSION['fname']` and `$_SESSION['userID']` by `$theFName` and `$theId`.

```
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $pass  = $_POST['pass'];
       $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);                
       $sql = "SELECT id, email, fname, lname, type FROM users WHERE `email`=? AND `pass`=?";              
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email,$pass);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($theId,$theEmail,$theFName,$theLname,$theType);
       if ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo 'true';
            $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'] = true;
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $theFName;
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $theId;
       } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
```

in JavaScript file I have

```
 <script>  
  var tok = "var UID = "<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>"; 
  console.log("The Id is " + UID)
</script>
```

but I am getting empty string!

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you start the session?

Comment: ...in all files using sessions? Error reporting will tell you http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php while making sure the JS code is in a `.php` file.

Comment: I won't stand here all day, I have better things to do than wait around like someone's personal butler. Good luck, I am moving on.

Comment: Thanks for reply , yes I have started the Session on the all pages

Comment: I am in fact using the `$_SESSION['fname'] = $theFName;` in the HTML and working (So Session and Database query ar3 working properly!) but in JavaScript not working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do in the JS file, but it is not valid JS in any case - the quotes don't match and it seems like you are trying to do an assignment inside a string.

I think what you are looking for is something more along the lines of this:

```
<script>  
  var UID = "<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>"; 
  console.log("The Id is " + UID)
</script>
```

However, please note that dynamically generating JS files using PHP is likely not the best way to go about this. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/1091445) SO answer on the various methods you can use to pass variables from PHP to JS, along with their various pros and cons.